# While trying to query a database, im getting back what I think is the table header names instead of the values

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to write a simple chat script using php and mysql and i think i am returning the actual values of "Sender" and "Message" without ever getting the values of those columns.  below is my index page where i am trying to display the queried results.

```
<?php
require('/includes/core.inc.php');
if (isset($_POST['send'])){

    if(send_msg($_POST['sender'], $_POST['message'])){

        echo "Message Sent";

    }

    else{
        echo "message not sent";

    }
}
?>

<div id ="messages">
<?php

$messages = get_msg();
$i = 0;
foreach($messages as $message){


    $i = $i + 1;
    echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'][$i].'Sent</strong><br/>';
    echo $message['message'][$i].'<br /><br />';
    }
?>



</div><!---Messages-->

<form action ="index.php" method="post">
    <lable>Enter Name:<input type="text" name="sender"/></label>
    <lable>Enter Message:<input type='text' name="message"></label>
    <input type = "submit" name="send" value="send message">
    </form>
```

and then here is my actual chat function.  i know i am getting the values into and out of the database as i can check it through phpmyadmin but why isn't it displaying ont he page?  thanks so much for any answer you may have for me ! sorry for bad english.

```
<?php


function get_msg(){

    $query = "SELECT 'Sender', 'Message' FROM chat";

    $run = mysql_query($query);

    $messages = array();

    while($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){

        $messages[] = array('sender'=>$message['Sender'], 
                            'message'=>$message['Message']);



    }

    return $messages;



}

function send_msg($sender, $message){

    if(!empty($sender) && !empty($message)){

        $sender = mysql_real_escape_string($sender);
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

        $query = "INSERT INTO chat VALUES (null, '{$sender}','{$message}')";

        if($run = mysql_query($query)){

            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{

        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $query = "SELECT 'Sender', 'Message' FROM chat";
```

should be

```
  $query = "SELECT Sender, Message FROM chat";
```

In the first case you select the fixed strings `Sender` and `Message` because single quotes.